# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type (NEW)

Tags: typescript, object, assign

This is the same crap annoying TS problem with assigning known keys to object dynamically, just my case is that, I'm sending the whole object in handler function.

In this case crap TS don't know to understand even I'm casting the attributeProp as keyof attribute or attributeProp as keyof typeof attribute, saying, Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.

```
  const onChange = (
    attribute: TObjectTypeAttribute,
    attributeProp: string,
    attributeValue: any
  ) => {
    attribute[attributeProp] = attributeValue;
//  Both not working
//  attribute[attributeProp as keyof attribute] = attributeValue;
//  attribute[attributeProp as keyof typeof attribute] = attributeValue;
  };
```

TS version 5.x

Answer (score 0):

`keyof` takes a type, not an object:

```
attribute[attributeProp as keyof TObjectTypeAttribute] = attributeValue;
```

But then you don't even need the `as`, just give the right type to `attributeProp`:

```
const onChange = (
    attribute: TObjectTypeAttribute,
    attributeProp: keyof TObjectTypeAttribute,
    attributeValue: any
) => {
    attribute[attributeProp] = attributeValue;
};
```